# Using TortoiseGit and visual studio build-in git in parallel

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tortoisegit

I have a small team on my working place.
All of us are using Visual Studio 2013 and tortoisegit about a year and work well.

I have a concern if someone using Visual Studio 2013 built-in GIT to work, does it possible make any negative affect to the REPO?

Because we are using git 1.9.1 and i don't know what version of VS2013 is.
And i cannot disable the functionality of VS2013 git on each work mate's PC.

Thanks you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality given by Visual Studio 2013s git integration is somewhat limited. The only negative effect is that Visual Studio 2013 has a "sync" button which does a fetch, merge and push, which can do weird things to your history. Other than that there should be no negative effects of using both.

I personally use VS2013 to create commits, but use the command line to do things VS2013 doesn't offer like rebasing.